# how can i repeat this method 3/5 times or effect remain for 10-15sec, in c++ ,tried while loop but dont work somehow

Tags: loops, while-loop, effect

<I tried the while Loop method we can see here but I didn't repeat the PumpBomb_Exp in Actual Game Testing IDK what I did wrong here
its method of grenade that explodes but I want to repeat it 3 to 4 time like keep exploding or show sprites till 10-15 sec>

```
  public PumpBomb_Exp(Ent, Float:Origin[3], Owner, Team)
    {
        new i=1;
        while(i<10){
        // Do Effect
        message_begin(MSG_BROADCAST, SVC_TEMPENTITY)
        write_byte(TE_EXPLOSION)
        engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, Origin[0])
        engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, Origin[1])
        engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, Origin[2] + 16.0)
        write_short(g_Exp_SprId)
        write_byte(50)  // scale in 0.1's
        write_byte(30)  // framerate
        write_byte(4)   // flags
        message_end()  
    
    // Play Sound
    

    emit_sound(Ent, CHAN_BODY, WeaponSounds[0], 1.0, ATTN_NORM, 0, PITCH_NORM)
    
        static Float:PlayerOrigin[3]
        for(new i = 0; i < g_MaxPlayers; i++)
        {
            if(!is_user_alive(i))
                continue
            if(get_player_team(i) == Team)
                continue
            pev(i, pev_origin, PlayerOrigin)
            if(get_distance_f(Origin, PlayerOrigin) > PUMPKIN_RADIUS)
                continue
                
            if(!is_user_connected(Owner)) Owner = i
            ExecuteHamB(Ham_TakeDamage, i, "grenade", Owner, PUMPKIN_DAMAGE, DMG_CRUSH)
        }
        static Float:flOrigin [ 3 ]
        pev (Ent, pev_origin, flOrigin )
        new id = pev(Ent, pev_owner)
        engfunc(EngFunc_EmitSound, Ent, CHAN_WEAPON,g_soundexpl, 1.0, ATTN_NORM, 0, PITCH_NORM)
```

//Explode   its show explosion effect & ring,ring2 are add more details of explosion

```
engfunc(EngFunc_MessageBegin, MSG_PVS, SVC_TEMPENTITY, flOrigin, 0)
        write_byte(TE_EXPLOSION)
        engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[0])
        engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[1])
        engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[2]+50.0)
        write_short(spriteexpl)
        write_byte(30)
        write_byte(10)
        write_byte(0)
        message_end()
        
        
//Light

        message_begin(MSG_BROADCAST, SVC_TEMPENTITY)
        write_byte(TE_DLIGHT)
        engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[0])
        engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[1])
        engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[2])
        write_byte(45)//Radius
        write_byte(250) // r
        write_byte(150) // g
        write_byte(50)  // b
        write_byte(15)  //Life
        write_byte(10)
        message_end() 
        
            
//Decal
            engfunc(EngFunc_MessageBegin, MSG_PAS, SVC_TEMPENTITY, flOrigin, 0)
            write_byte(TE_WORLDDECAL)
            engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[0])
            engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[1])
            engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[2])
            write_byte(engfunc(EngFunc_DecalIndex,"{scorch3"))
            message_end()
            
//Ring
            engfunc(EngFunc_MessageBegin, MSG_PVS, SVC_TEMPENTITY, flOrigin, 0)
            write_byte(TE_BEAMCYLINDER) // TE id
            engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[0])    // x
            engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[1])    // y
            engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[2])    // z
            engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[0])    // x axis
            engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[1])    // y axis
            engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[2] + 35)   // z axis
            write_short(g_sprRing)  // sprite
            write_byte(0)   // startframe
            write_byte(0)   // framerate
            write_byte(10)  // life
            write_byte(65)  // width
            write_byte(0)   // noise
            write_byte(255)     // red
            write_byte(155)     // green
            write_byte(55)  // blue
            write_byte(200)     // brightness
            write_byte(0)   // speed
            message_end()
```

//Ring2

```
engfunc(EngFunc_MessageBegin, MSG_PVS, SVC_TEMPENTITY, flOrigin, 0)
                write_byte(TE_BEAMCYLINDER)         // TE id
                engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[0])        // x
                engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[1])        // y
                engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[2])        // z
                engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[0])        // x axis
                engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[1])        // y axis
                engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[2] + 65)   // z axis
                write_short(g_sprRing)  // sprite
                write_byte(0)       // startframe
                write_byte(0)       // framerate
                write_byte(10)      // life
                write_byte(35)      // width
                write_byte(0)       // noise
                write_byte(255)     // red
                write_byte(155)     // green
                write_byte(55)      // blue
                write_byte(200)     // brightness
                write_byte(0)       // speed
                message_end()
                
                //Ring3
                
            
                engfunc(EngFunc_MessageBegin, MSG_PVS, SVC_TEMPENTITY, flOrigin, 0)
                    write_byte(TE_BEAMCYLINDER)         // TE id
                    engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[0])        // x
                    engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[1])        // y
                    engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[2])        // z
                    engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[0])        // x axis
                    engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[1])        // y axis
                    engfunc(EngFunc_WriteCoord, flOrigin[2] + 95)   // z axis
                    write_short(g_sprRing)  // sprite
                    write_byte(0)       // startframe
                    write_byte(0)       // framerate
                    write_byte(10)      // life
                    write_byte(15)      // width
                    write_byte(0)       // noise
                    write_byte(255)         // red
                    write_byte(155)         // green
                    write_byte(55)      // blue
                    write_byte(200)         // brightness
                    write_byte(0)       // speed
                    message_end() 
                    i++;
                }
```

Comment: Please tag with language.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)